# How to porting java apps with postgresql to parse platform

Tags: javascript, postgresql, parse-platform

I'm new in parse platform. My old apps used java apps with postgresql as database. Now i want to migrate it with parse platform.

Please explain me how to do that?

Thank you...

Comment: I think you'll need to ask the parse.com technical support people about that.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
my plan to do:
1. export/convert postgreSql database to csv format
2. import that csv format database to parse.com databrowser.

But i still did not get best way to do that...

Comment: `pg_dump --data-only -Fd` will give you a directory full of tab-separated data, one file per table, with a special marker for NULL. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html for details on the format. Or you can use `\copy` in `psql` directly, table by table, or script it with python/perl/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of your data model, a dump/import may not be a good option. If your model is simple, an import may work ok. But bear in mind that you are moving from a SQL database to a NoSQL based service. If you have join tables etc in your PostgreSQL db, these are not the way to go with Parse. The query paradigm is different.

Moving from SQL to NoSQL is mostly not about export and import, but planning your data model for NoSQL. Your best option is to plan out your new model (after reading up on NoSQL), and then create a script that will pull data from your old database and push it to your new. Unless your database is simple, this operation should not be taken ligthly.

If your app becomes very popular, the effort you put in now could be what makes or breaks your service later on.